# How to export PDF file from datatable in nopcommerce 4.3?

Tags: pdf, button, model-view-controller, datatable, nopcommerce

In nopcommerce 4.3, I want to export pdf file from datatable.

I wrote code but didnt work for me, infact any type of export button is not showing, also there is no error showing.

Here is my code,

In **_Table.Definition.cshtml(Nop.Web => Areas => Admin => Views => Shared)** file I modified some code i.e.

```
.....

@if (Model.RefreshButton)
{
    <text>    
        buttons: ['copyHtml5','excelHtml5','csvHtml5','pdfHtml5'], (ADD NEW BUTTON FOR PDF)
    </text>

    <text>
        buttons: [{
        name: 'refresh',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-refresh" style="padding-left: 5px"></i>',
        action: function () {
            @if (Model.ServerSide)
            {
                <text>
                updateTable('#@Model.Name');
                </text>
            }
            else
            {
                <text>
                    updateTableSrc('#@Model.Name');
                </text>
            }
        }
    }],
    </text>
}

dom: 'Bfrtip',


.....
```